# What is the pressure drop in a venturi with a compressible fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, flow

I would like to know if there is an equation to predict the pressure drop in a [venturi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_tube#Venturi_tubes) device using a compressible fluid as the working medium. In particular, I'd like to use this equation to predict the amount of vacuum created for a given $\Delta p$ across the device. Simplifying assumptions can be made, such as equivalent inlet and outlet areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. [Bernoulli's equation has its compressible form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Compressible_flow_in_fluid_dynamics).